# How to take an object from a class to another activity?

Tags: android-studio, class, object

I have a login app that has to have a user class with the user information in an object. But now I'm trying to figure out how I could compare the user object with the username and password the user inputs to see if it is correct. So I need to be able to see for example if the user inserts "Jason" into the username txt and "Sword" into the  password txt I need to see if it is correct and matches the one in the user class. Does anyone know how I would go about doing so? Any help would be muchly appreciated I'm just really stuck.

```
public class User {

static String userName;
static String password;
static String favColor;

public User(String userName, String password, String favColor){
    this.userName = userName;
    this.password = password;
    this.favColor = favColor;

}

public class UserGroup{

    // Created user Objects for each user

    User  user1 = new User ("Jason", "Sword", "Red");
    User user2 = new User ("Billy", "Dinosaur", "Blue");
    User user3 = new User ("Zack", "Elephant", "Black");
    User user4 = new User ("Trini", "Tiger", "Yellow");
    User user5 = new User ("Kimberly", "Bird", "Pink");

}
```

}

```
      logInBt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void  onClick(View view) {

            String userET = userEditText.getText().toString();
            String userPassword = passwordEditText.getText().toString();

            UserGroup users = new UserGroup();
            if (userET.equals(users.user1.userName)&& userPassword.equals(users.user1.password ){
           // write here what you want user 1 to do after login
            }else if (userET.equals(users.user2.userName)&& userPassword.equals(users.user2.password ){
                // write here what you want user 2 to do after login
            }

        }
    });

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

you have to make the user Class filed  static to reached it any where

or you can use instate of it and i will use instate to do not change your code

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {


super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

final Button logInBt = findViewById(R.id.buttonLogIn);
final EditText userEditText = findViewById(R.id.editTextTextPersonName);
final EditText passwordEditText = findViewById(R.id.editTextTextPassword);



logInBt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void  onClick(View view) {

        String userET = userEditText.getText().toString();
        String userPassword = passwordEditText.getText().toString();
UserGroup users = new UserGroup();
if (userEt.equals(users.user1.userName)&& userPassword.equals(users.user1.password ){
// write here what you want user 1 to do after login
 }else if (userEt.equals(users.user2.userName)&& userPassword.equals(users.user2.password ){
   // write here what you want user 2 to do after login
 }



    }
});
```

do else if to check all the user and you can change it to a list of users to make it easer

Comment: Awesome thank you but for some reason in the onClick where it says user1.userName the user1 says cannot resolve symbol 'user1' why would this be happening when the class is now static?

Comment: i edit my answer to use the instant right sorry for that you can use my code now or you can make the filed user1 static (not the class) and use it like this (UserGroup.user1.username)

Comment: Thanks Sideeg!! So use the code you have done and then make the object user1 static? Is that what you mean?

Comment: Yeah I did take your code and the UserGroup users = new UserGroup(); has the rror cannot resolve symbol 'UserGroup' and the same goes with the 'user1' as well for some reason. Thats with the fact I have changed anything in my user class.

Comment: update the question with your full new code to let me see what is the error

Comment: i think you have } after userGroup class must be deleted

Comment: No that cant be deleted or else im missing a }

Comment: please edit your question and put all the code in one code paragraph

Comment: In one paragraph? The user class is in a separate class from the Onclick which is in an activity

Comment: Ok thats what i was needed to know >>> in this case you have to import the userGroup Class in you activity

Comment: So sorry I didnt even realise i didnt add that part in. So sorry!! Yeah ive been trying to figure out ways to import the userGroup class into my MainActivity but havent came across anything

Comment: i think this https://www.studytonight.com/java/package-in-java.php#:~:text=To%20import%20java%20package%20into,by%20directly%20using%20its%20name. will help you know how to import class

Comment: Ok thank you I will have a look over this in the morning

Comment: please if my answer help you accepted it and up vote it